# Exchanging axis values in python(jupyter notebook) under gca

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.gca()
df = pd.read_csv (r'AMZN.csv')
df['moving_average'] = df['Close'].rolling(window = 20).mean()
df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Close',ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='moving_average', color='red', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Date is on x axis. I want to change it to y axis. And vice-versa. How would it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply swapping the x and y data as

```
df.plot(kind='line', x='Close', y= 'Date', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line', x='moving_average', y='Date', color='red', ax=ax)
```

Comment: I have tried but it is showing error due to the ax thing. @Sheldore